How to access all enum members through class variable?
I have a class, and I want to access the members of some enum through it, in favor of encapsulation and convenience. i.e: I wouldn't like the client code to have to import and directly deal with the enums.
So, ideally, I would like have something like this in the client code:
print(DesignSystem.colors.white);
print(DesignSystem.spacings.xs);

Right now I have achieved what I want doing the following, but it feels kind of cumbersome:
enum Color {
  black(value: '#000000'),
  white(value: '#FFFFFF');
 
  final String value;
  
  const Color({required this.value});
 }

class _Colors {
  final Color black = Color.black;
  final Color white = Color.white;
}

enum Spacing {
  xs(value: 5),
  sm(value: 10);
 
  final int value;
  
  const Spacing({required this.value});
}

class _Spacings {
  final Spacing xs = Spacing.xs;
  final Spacing sm = Spacing.sm;
}

class DesignSystem {
  static final _Colors colors = _Colors();
  static final _Spacings spacings = _Spacings();
  
}

So is there any other way that I might be missing? I've tried to directly assign the enum classes as class variables of DesignSystem but it doesn't seem to be possible in Dart.

If I were you I wouldn't do that ,

Could you elaborate on why? @aymanomara

The design in your example achieves encapsulation, but it introduces unnecessary complexity. this approach can be simplified while maintaining encapsulation and convenience:
class DesignSystem {
static const colors = Color;
static const spacings = Spacing;
}
or even use colors and spaces directly

It is not currently possible to declare a type as a nested member of another type, so what you are doing is unfortunately the only real way to accomplish this.
There's a more efficient way, though, by using collection classes instead of enums and using constants instead of instance variables.
class Color {
  final String value;

  const Color(this.value);
}

class ColorCollection {
  static const instance = ColorCollection._();

  const ColorCollection._();

  final black = const Color('#000000');
  final white = const Color('#FFFFFF');
}

class DesignSystem {
  static ColorCollection get colors => ColorCollection.instance;
}

void main() {
  final black = DesignSystem.colors.black;
}

